# R: Convert obscure table into matrix

Tags: r, data.table

I have table that looks like this:

```
Row Col Value
1   1   31
1   2   56
1   8   13
2   1   83
2   2   51
2   9   16
3   2   53
```

I need to convert this table into matrix (`Row` column represents rows and `Col` column represents columns). For the output like this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
1 31 56 NA NA NA NA NA 13 NA
2 81 51 NA NA NA NA NA NA 16
3 NA 53 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I believe that there is quick way to do what I want as my solution would be looping for every row/column combination and `cbind` everything.

**Reproducible example:**

```
require(data.table)
myTable <- data.table(
           Row = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
           Col = c(1,2,8,1,2,9,1),
           Value = c(31,56,13,83,51,16,53))
```

Comment: Your data is inconsistent; the final Col value is 2 in your "I have table that looks like this" and 1 in your "Reproducible example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xtabs` in base R is perfect for this if you can live with "0" where you have `NA`.

This would be the basic approach:

```
xtabs(Value ~ Row + Col, myTable)
#    Col
# Row  1  2  8  9
#   1 31 56 13  0
#   2 83 51  0 16
#   3 53  0  0  0
```

However, that doesn't fill in the gaps, because not all factor levels are available. You can do this separately, or on-the-fly, like this:

```
xtabs(Value ~ factor(Row, sequence(max(Row))) + 
      factor(Col, sequence(max(Col))), myTable)
#                                factor(Col, sequence(max(Col)))
# factor(Row, sequence(max(Row)))  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
#                               1 31 56  0  0  0  0  0 13  0
#                               2 83 51  0  0  0  0  0  0 16
#                               3 53  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

By extension, this means that if the "Row" and "Col" values are factors, `dcast.data.table` *should* also work:

```
dcast.data.table(myTable, Row ~ Col, value.var = "Value", drop = FALSE)
```

(But it doesn't in my test for some reason. I had to do `library(reshape2); dcast(myTable, Row ~ Col, value.var = "Value", drop = FALSE)` to get it to work, thus not taking advantage of "data.table" speed.)

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward:

```
dat <- data.frame(
         Row = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3),
       Col = c(1,2,8,1,2,9,1),
       Value = c(31,56,13,83,51,16,53))
m = matrix(NA, nrow = max(dat$Row), ncol = max(dat$Col))
m[cbind(dat$Row, dat$Col)] = dat$Value
m
```

Comment: this is not the expected result.

Comment: How long this should take for tables with dim (1000x1000)? Solution is simple, clean and easy to understand, however takes some time.

Comment: @SimBea, you mean the result should be 1000 X 1000?

Comment: @SimBea This answer should be the fastest way if you want `NA`s all over, yeah. A sparse matrix is better for some algebraic operations and may take up less space.

Answer (score 4):

**Sparse matrix.** You probably want a sparse matrix

```
require(Matrix) # doesn't require installation
mySmat <- with(myTable,sparseMatrix(Row,Col,x=Value))
```

which gives

```
3 x 9 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] 31 56 . . . . . 13  .
[2,] 83 51 . . . . .  . 16
[3,] 53  . . . . . .  .  .
```

---

**Matrix.** If you really need a `matrix`-class object with `NA`s, there's

```
myMat <- as.matrix(mySmat)
myMat[myMat==0] <- NA
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   31   56   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   13   NA
[2,]   83   51   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   16
[3,]   53   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

*Efficiency considerations.* For shorter code:

```
myMat <- with(myTable,as.matrix(sparseMatrix(Row,Col,x=Value)))
myMat[myMat==0] <- NA
```

For faster speed (but slower than creating a sparse matrix), initialize to `NA` and then fill, as @jimmyb and @bgoldst do:

```
myMat <- with(myTable,matrix(,max(Row),max(Col)))
myMat[cbind(myTable$Row,myTable$Col)] <- myTable$Value
```

This workaround is only necessary if you insist on `NA`s over zeros. A sparse matrix is almost certainly what you should use. Creating and working with it should be faster; and storing it should be less memory-intensive.

Comment: Nice you can even wrap it with `as.matrix` for a "clean visualization" !

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel You mean in one line? Unfortunately, I can't figure a way to put the replace-with-`NA` thing into there. Seems like `as.matrix` for a sparse matrix should have an option of reading zeros as `NA`s, but I can find no such option. Anyway, I'll write the two-liner :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most concise and performant way to achieve this is to preallocate the matrix with NAs, and then assign a vector slice by manually computing the linear indexes from `Row` and `Col`:

```
df <- data.frame(Row=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3), Col=c(1,2,8,1,2,9,2), Value=c(31,56,13,83,51,16,53) );
m <- matrix(NA,max(df$Row),max(df$Col));
m[(df$Col-1)*nrow(m)+df$Row] <- df$Value;
m;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
## [1,]   31   56   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   13   NA
## [2,]   83   51   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   16
## [3,]   NA   53   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: :) By the way, in my experience, linear and matrix indices are about equally fast for assignment like this. But anyway, there's nothing faster than this answer that I know of.